# paginator is not reading data in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, paginator

I am trying to implement a paginator with table in angular material. The data source comes from a `Node.js` server and works fine. However the paginator is like not reading the data table. I am not getting any error, but it is simply not working. Really appreciate your answers.

The Template -

```html
<h3>Lista casos</h3>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="listaCasos" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="idcaso">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID Caso </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let caso"> {{caso.ID_CASO}} </td>
    </ng-container>  

    <ng-container matColumnDef="estado">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Estado </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let caso"> {{caso.ESTADO_CASO}} </td>

    </ng-container>  

    <ng-container matColumnDef="causa">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Causa </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let caso"> {{caso.CAUSA}} </td>
    </ng-container> 

    <ng-container matColumnDef="detalles">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Detalles </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let caso"> 
        <a routerLink="/dashboard/gestion/{{caso.ID_CASO}}"><button mat-button>Ver caso</button></a>
      </td>
    </ng-container> 


    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table> 
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

The Component -

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CasosService } from './casos.service';
import { interCaso } from '../../interfaces/interCaso';
import {AfterViewInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-casos',
  templateUrl: './casos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./casos.component.css']
})
export class CasosComponent implements OnInit , AfterViewInit{

  listaCasos: interCaso[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['idcaso' , 'causa' , 'estado' , 'detalles'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<interCaso>(this.listaCasos);

  constructor(private casosService: CasosService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCasos();
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  
  getCasos(){
    this.casosService.getCasos()
      .subscribe((casos : interCaso[]) => {        
        this.listaCasos = casos;
        console.log(casos);
      })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the html, you are binding `dataSource` to `listaCasos`. This will cause the table to always remain filled up will *all* data, because the paginator doesn't respond to the `listaCasos` property, it responds to the `dataSource` property. Therefore, the binding should be to the `dataSource` property -

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

2. In the component, you are initializing the `dataSource` with `listaCasos` on declaration. But, `listaCasos` will not be populated with data until `ngOnInit()` gets called. So, do not initialize the `dataSource` on declaration. Instead populate it inside the `ngAfterViewInit()` method -

```js
// leave the dataSource uninitialized
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<interCaso>();

//populate dataSource here
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.data = this.listaCasos;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

**Edit :**
Sorry I tested with static data. But, in your case the `casosService` is fetching data asynchronously, and there is a chance of `ngAfterViewInit()` being called while the data has not arrived yet. Therefore, it would be better if you populate the data inside the subscription to the service call -

```js
// populate dataSource here
getCasos(){
    this.casosService.getCasos()
      .subscribe((casos : interCaso[]) => {        
        //this.listaCasos = casos;
        this.dataSource.data = casos;
        console.log(casos);
      })
}
```

You'll not be needing `listaCasos` anymore.

Comment: makes sense, but i did it and now is not reading the data.

Comment: @DanielChavarriaChavarrio Please check the Edit.

Comment: yes , indeed now its working, thank you so much. highest score to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Try Using

Assign `paginator` for `MatTable` where u are assigning the data to the table.Try like following,

```
getCasos(){
    this.casosService.getCasos()
      .subscribe((casos : interCaso[]) => { 
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(casos);        
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
}
```

Working **`stackblitz`** example: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uf1sdt-zv5te5?file=src/app/table-multiple-header-footer-example.html**